# Conan and Raspberry Pico, how to use together?

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi, sdk, conan

Good morning!

I'm rewriting this question because, after a lot of reading and try-fails, I go further on that but I get staked again.

What I'm trying to accomplice here is: Use Conan as a Package manager for the embedded device "Raspberry PICO" from my Mac (with CLion)

The change from the previous question is that now I'm creating a package and I do not use only the "standalone" packages manager.

This "package" is on [github.com](https://github.com/jBernavaPrah/conan-blink-pico). To install and try to compile it, you will need also the [Pico SDK](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/pico/raspberry-pi-pico-c-sdk.pdf).

Some facts:

- The new c++ project without Conan but with SDK is compiling and working on an embedded device.
- The Conan project without Pico SDK is compiling correctly.
- I really tried every possible configuration on the profile file and there are two mainly configuration profiles that brings to two different errors during build:

The first one is without any environments. This is because on CLion I'm not adding any environment and the project itself (without conan, but oblivious with SDK for pico) is builder correctly.

```
[settings]
os_build=Macos
arch_build=x86_64

os=Linux
arch=armv7
# os=Macos
# arch=x86_64

# compiler=apple-clang
compiler=gcc
# compiler.version=12.0
compiler.version=9.2
# compiler.libcxx=libc++
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++

build_type=Release

[options]
[build_requires]
[env]
```

ps. The commented lines are additional tests that resolve on the same result after `conan build .`.

The error is this:

```
jure.prah@MacBook-Pro-di-Jure conan-blink-mosfet % conan build .  
Using lockfile: '/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/conan.lock'
Using cached profile from lockfile
conanfile.py (blink/0.1): Calling build()
conanfile.py (blink/0.1): CMake command: cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/build/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/package" "/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/src"
Using PICO_SDK_PATH from environment ('/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/pico-sdk')
PICO_SDK_PATH is /Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/pico-sdk
Defaulting PICO_PLATFORM to rp2040 since not specified.
-- Defaulting build type to 'Release' since not specified.
Using Conan toolchain through /Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/build/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake.
-- Conan toolchain: Setting CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=ON (options.fPIC)
-- Conan toolchain: Setting BUILD_SHARED_LIBS= OFF
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.5.12050022
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.5.12050022
-- The ASM compiler identification is Clang
-- Found assembler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
Using Conan toolchain through .
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Using Conan toolchain through .
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Defaulting PICO target board to pico since not specified.
Using board configuration from /Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/pico-sdk/src/boards/include/boards/pico.h
-- Found Python3: /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 (found version "3.9.6") found components: Interpreter 
TinyUSB available at /Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/portable/raspberrypi/rp2040; adding USB support.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/build/Release
conanfile.py (blink/0.1): CMake command: cmake --build '/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/build/Release'
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/blink.dir/blink.cpp.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX static library libblink.a
[ 50%] Built target blink
Scanning dependencies of target bs2_default
[ 75%] Building ASM object pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/CMakeFiles/bs2_default.dir/compile_time_choice.S.o
/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:89:1: error: unknown directive
.syntax unified
^
/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:90:1: error: unknown directive
.cpu cortex-m0plus
^
/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:91:1: error: unknown directive
.thumb
^
/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:93:15: error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
.section .text
              ^
/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:101:1: error: unknown directive
.type _stage2_boot,%function
^
/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:102:1: error: unknown directive
.thumb_func
^
/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:104:11: error: unknown token in expression
    push {lr}
          ^
[...]
         ^
/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/boot2_w25q080.S:285:1: error: unknown directive
.ltorg
^
make[2]: *** [pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/CMakeFiles/bs2_default.dir/compile_time_choice.S.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/CMakeFiles/bs2_default.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
ERROR: conanfile.py (blink/0.1): Error in build() method, line 40
        cmake.build()
        ConanException: Error 2 while executing cmake --build '/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/build/Release'
```

The second profile configuration is based on [the example from conan.com](https://docs.conan.io/en/1.23/systems_cross_building/cross_building.html#windows-to-raspberry-pi-linux-arm) (thanks to @uilianres) and sets the environments.:

```
toolchain_path=/usr/local/bin
toolchain=arm-none-eabi

[settings]
os_build=Macos
arch_build=x86_64
#os=Macos
#arch=x86_64
os=Linux
arch=armv7
compiler=apple-clang
# compiler=gcc
compiler.version=12.0
# compiler.version=9.2
compiler.libcxx=libc++
# compiler.libcxx=libstdc++
build_type=Release

[options]
[build_requires]
[env]
CONAN_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=$toolchain_path/
AR=$toolchain-ar
AS=$toolchain-as
CC=$toolchain-gcc
CXX=$toolchain-g++
STRIP=$toolchain-strip
```

Using command `conan build .` resolve on different error:

```
jure.prah@MacBook-Pro-di-Jure conan-blink-mosfet % conan build .
Using lockfile: '/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/conan.lock'
Using cached profile from lockfile
conanfile.py (blink/0.1): Calling build()
conanfile.py (blink/0.1): CMake command: cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/build/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/package" "/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/src"
Using PICO_SDK_PATH from environment ('/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/pico-sdk')
PICO_SDK_PATH is /Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/pico-sdk
Defaulting PICO_PLATFORM to rp2040 since not specified.
-- Defaulting build type to 'Release' since not specified.
Using Conan toolchain through /Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/build/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake.
-- Conan toolchain: Setting CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=ON (options.fPIC)
-- Conan toolchain: Setting BUILD_SHARED_LIBS= OFF
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.2.1
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: /usr/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - no
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
Using Conan toolchain through .
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
Using Conan toolchain through .
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc - broken
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.21.0/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/build/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_69910/fast && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_69910.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_69910.dir/build
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_69910.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    /usr/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0  -O3 -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk -fPIE -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_69910.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/build/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_69910
    /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.21.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_69910.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -O3 -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/cmTC_69910.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_69910 
    /usr/local/Cellar/arm-none-eabi-gcc/9-2019-q4-major/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol arch_paths_first; defaulting to 0000000000008018
    /usr/local/Cellar/arm-none-eabi-gcc/9-2019-q4-major/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/local/Cellar/arm-none-eabi-gcc/9-2019-q4-major/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): in function `exit':
    exit.c:(.text.exit+0x2c): undefined reference to `_exit'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[1]: *** [cmTC_69910] Error 1
    make: *** [cmTC_69910/fast] Error 2
   
  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/build/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/build/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
ERROR: conanfile.py (blink/0.1): Error in build() method, line 39
        cmake.configure()
        ConanException: Error 1 while executing cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/build/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/package" "/Users/jure.prah/CLionProjects/rpi-pico/conan-blink-mosfet/src"
```

Also here I did all the variants and tests, but everything leads to this error. Besides, I checked the toolchain paths and there are correct.

I'm completely lost now. :(

Comment: Try setting up a profile https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/systems_cross_building/cross_building.html

Comment: Follow the documentation pointed by Alan. If it doesn't work, update your question with your profile and compiler used. Your question is clear but some important details are missing.

Comment: Hi @uilianries, I have updated the question, I hope I added all the information you need. Thanks you so much!!

Comment: Are you really using apple-clang for cross-building? Also, you detailed which SDK you are using. Is /usr/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc a valid path in your system? There is an example using Windows, but you can update to Mac too: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/systems_cross_building/cross_building.html#windows-to-raspberry-pi-linux-arm

Comment: Yes, I'm using apple-clang for cross-building and the SDK is correctly located on that path. 
After some further investigations and tries, I still cannot compile packages nor use them on existing projects with the platform for rpi pico. 

What I found interesting is that the standard configuration on CLion (Mac) compile correctly the project for the platform "pico", thanks to the "pico_sdk_init.cmake" that configure the compiler I guess. I think I need to tell Conan that need to import this file or use this file somewhere... But it's my guess :(

Comment: Hi @uilianries, I have rewrite completely the question with, I hope, more information.

Comment: @jbernavaprah is much more clear now. It seems like cmake didn't understand that you are trying to cross-compile, so it build a small example using your sdk and try to run on your machine, which is incompatible. The variable CONAN_CMAKE_SYSROOT is not listed in your profile, it's important to declare that you are cross-building. Another option is using cmake toolchain file, it's a native cmake feature which is supported by conan too. There is an example here: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/systems_cross_building/cross_building.html#examples

Comment: @jbernavaprah still about the cmake toolchain file, if you are not familiarized with, there is a post here: https://medium.com/@au42/the-useful-raspberrypi-cross-compile-guide-ea56054de187 which has an example for Rpi. The idea is declaring where your SDK is installed, which cpu is your target. Regards